# ios screen capture-related functionality inhert viewcontroller invisible

Tags: ios, screenshot

When working with screen capture-related functionality, I want to create a BaseViewController to provide functionality for other UIViewControllers. However, I have set up the loadView method in BaseViewController and provided a property to allow UIViewController instances to customize it independently.

```
- (void)loadView {
NSLog(@"BaseViewController loadView");
if (self.banScreenShot) {
    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    textField.secureTextEntry = YES;
    textField.enabled = NO;
    if (textField.subviews.firstObject != nil) {
        self.view = textField.subviews.firstObject;
    } else {
        self.view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    }
} else {
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] init];
}
self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,
                             [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width,
                             [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height);
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

When I set up some components in the storyboard and inherit from BaseViewController in MainViewController, setting

```
 self.banScreenShot = YES;
```

the components in the storyboard become invisible, and the view becomes entirely white. How can I allow MainViewController to have its own display functionality while still inheriting the loadView functionality from BaseViewController?
Thank you.

MainViewController header file:

```
 #import "BaseViewController.h"

 @interface MainViewController : BaseViewController
 @end
```

.m file

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
NSLog(@"ViewController viewDidLoad");
self.banScreenShot = YES;
 }
```

Comment: You should be aware that the secure text fileld hack to prevent screen shots no longer works on iOS 17

Comment: Also, your code doesn't make sense; you have implemented functionality in `loadView` but you are setting the property in `viewDidLoad`, which runs after `loadView`.

Comment: How are you adding all of the views for `MainViewController`? As you have implemented `loadView` you are taking full responsibility for the view loading process.  You probably want to add the pointless text field in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: MainViewController is bind in the storyboard init viewcontroller class,my storyboard have more ui elements ,but when I set the inhert BaseViewcontroller, the all elements is invisible.

Comment: From the [`loadView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621454-loadview) documentation *If you use Interface Builder to create your views and initialize the view controller, you must not override this method.* - As per my previous comment, you probably want to add the view in `viewDidLoad` of your superclass, not in `loadView`